# Optimizing closure to include only variables used by spawnees

Tags: compiler-construction, closures

```
m := 1 n := 2
fun D {
    d := 3 e := 4
    fun A {
        a := 5
        fun C {
            c := 6
            log d
            D()
        }
        C()
        D()
    }

    fun B {
        b := 7
        ret A 
    }

    B()()
}
```

Consider the above code, intentionally made hard to analyze "by hand", in function B, function A returned, and at that moment it must capture the environment, that would be `m` `n` `d` `e`. But after looking closely we can see that only `c` and probably `m` must be captured. I am not even sure about this. How to determine what variables to include in the closure evironment for `ret A` at the moment when the compiler generates the `ret A` assuming we have the AST?

Having that asked, I tell what I already tried. I tried to include just everything "below" the current function `B`, i.e. `{m n d e}`, but that leaves a lot of useless data in the heap in larger programs. I tried to build the tree of all possible "spawnees" (sorry for a lame term, do not know a better word) from `A` and then merging what they refer to, but I found out it could contain circular references and even the references to the parent functions of `B` and to `B` itself, at this moment I felt dizzy and after a couple of days thinking about it I just need help. So how do you build that list?

Comment: I think you can do this all on the stack with 'static links'. See: http://cinigl.io/posts/nested-variable-scoping

Comment: Are you asking about structuring the above during compilation? During machine code creation? Both?

Comment: @FrankC. during compilation mostly, say it was an interpreted language you still need to solve this anyway.

Comment: OK, in that case the link that @AlejandroC. provided is a good easy read or, if you want deeper engineering options/understanding, get a copy of Engineering a Compiler 2nd Edition by Keith Cooper, Linda Torczon.